# javascript detect adobe reader plugin for browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adobe-reader

If the pdf viewer plugin is not installed how to detect it and give a alert message to install pdf viewer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=detect+reader but perhaps http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any jquery plugin/script to detect Adobe Reader on user system ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900257/is-there-any-jquery-plugin-script-to-detect-adobe-reader-on-user-system)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I created a script on my blog for all major browsers to detect pdf reading capabilities. Even distinguishes between Chrome's PDF Viewer and Acrobat. you can get the code here:

[Detecting Adobe Acrobat in all browsers](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com/2011/01/detect-adobe-reader-plugin.html)

Comment: `browser_info.acrobat == null` might want to change that to `=`. (I can't edit it myself since edits must be at least 6 characters, apparently.)