# Execute script if plugin for <object> tag could not be loaded

Tags: javascript

I want to execute a script if my  tag failed to load.
Currently I have

```
<object src="http://foo.com/bar.pdf#navpanes=0" height="580" width="640">
    <a href="http://foo.com/bar.pdf">Click here to download the PDF</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
           window.alert('script executed');
           window.location.href = "http://foo.com/bar.pdf";
        //]]>
    </script>

</object>
```

But my script gets executed even the PDF plugin is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/) might be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect if the browser hat the adobe reader plugin installed:

[javascript detect adobe reader plugin for browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122061/javascript-detect-adobe-reader-plugin-for-browser)