# How to detect PDF Viewer plug-in from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, plugins, browser

I need a servlet code that would return the type of client browser and detect if there is a PDF Viewer plug-in installed on it.

I've tried using **HttpServletRequest**'s available **.getHeader("User-Agent")** like the following :

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
```

But it only returns the following browser types and no plug-ins :

"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.2)"

Is there any way that I could detect a PDF Viewer plug-in inside a servlet?

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a servlet and for sure not based on the user agent. Your best bet is performing the detection in a language which runs in the webbrowser itself, for example JavaScript. There are several JavaScript solutions around, see for example the comments and the answer of this question [javascript detect adobe reader plugin for browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122061/javascript-detect-adobe-reader-plugin-for-browser).

To pass this information from JavaScript to the Servlet, you could pass a request parameter by either ajax or manipulating a hidden field in a form, or set a cookie and then check it in the servlet. Request parameters and cookies are available by the usual `HttpServletRequest` methods.