# How test software what program opens an Adobe pdf form?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

What code could you put into an Adobe form to test what pdf viewer is used to open it, and display a warning if the wrong kind is used?

The reason is that if the survey is opened with anything other than Acrobat or Reader, it gets messed up and takes a lot of work to fix.

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score -1):

I dont believe you can do that inside the adobe form. But, You could find out the plugin that the browser uses to open pdf (information for this can be found here [javascript detect adobe reader plugin for browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122061/javascript-detect-adobe-reader-plugin-for-browser))

and then display a pdf with information to the user saying "you need adobe to open the pdf" if they use any other plugin.

Check this for example.. The real pdf opens only if the adobe reader plugin is installed and used on the browser.  http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5257E.PDF

Hope it helps..